# Reading in a fixed number of pipe delimited fields per row?

Tags: ruby, string, csv

I have a bunch of pipe-delimited files that weren't properly escaped for carriage returns when generated, and so I cant use the CR or newline characters to delimit the rows. I DO know however that each record has to have exactly 7 fields.

Splitting the fields is easy with the CSV library in Ruby 1.9 setting the 'col_sep' argument, but the 'row_sep' argument cannot be set because I have newlines within the fields.

Is there a way to parse a pipe-delimited file using a fixed number of fields as the row delimiter?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give an example of delimited string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way of doing it:

Build a sample string of seven words, with an embedded new-line in the 
middle of the string. There are three lines worth.

```
text = (["now is the\ntime for all good"] * 3).join(' ').gsub(' ', '|')
puts text
# >> now|is|the
# >> time|for|all|good|now|is|the
# >> time|for|all|good|now|is|the
# >> time|for|all|good
```

Process like this:

```
lines = []
chunks = text.gsub("\n", '|').split('|')
while (chunks.any?)
  lines << chunks.slice!(0, 7).join(' ')
end

puts lines
# >> now is the time for all good
# >> now is the time for all good
# >> now is the time for all good
```

So, that shows we can rebuild the rows.

Pretending that the words are actually columns from the pipe-delimited file we can make the code do the real thing by taking out the `.join(' ')`:

```
while (chunks.any?)
  lines << chunks.slice!(0, 7)
end

ap lines
# >> [
# >>     [0] [
# >>         [0] "now",
# >>         [1] "is",
# >>         [2] "the",
# >>         [3] "time",
# >>         [4] "for",
# >>         [5] "all",
# >>         [6] "good"
# >>     ],
# >>     [1] [
# >>         [0] "now",
# >>         [1] "is",
# >>         [2] "the",
# >>         [3] "time",
# >>         [4] "for",
# >>         [5] "all",
# >>         [6] "good"
# >>     ],
# >>     [2] [
# >>         [0] "now",
# >>         [1] "is",
# >>         [2] "the",
# >>         [3] "time",
# >>         [4] "for",
# >>         [5] "all",
# >>         [6] "good"
# >>     ]
# >> ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Say for instance you wanted to parse all charities in the IRS txt file that is pipe delimited.

Say you had a model called Charity that had all the same fields as your pipe delimited file.

```
class Charity < ActiveRecord::Base
   # http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToPub78DownloadLayout.do
   # http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToPub78Download.do
   attr_accessible :city, :country, :deductibility_status, :deductibility_status_description, :ein, :legal_name, :state
end
```

You can make a rake task called import.rake

```
namespace :import do

  desc "Import Pipe Delimted IRS 5013c Data "
  task :irs_data => :environment do

    require 'csv'

    txt_file_path = 'db/irs_5013cs.txt'
    results = File.open(txt_file_path).readlines do |line|
      line = line.split('|').each_slice(7)
    end

    # Order Field Notes
    # 1  EIN   Required
    # 2  Legal Name  Optional
    # 3  City  Optional
    # 4  State   Optional
    # 5  Deductibility Status  Optional
    # 6  Country   Optional - If Country is null, then Country is assumed to be   United   States
    # 7  Deductibility Status Description  Optional

    results.each do |row|
      row = row.split('|').each_slice(7).to_a.first
      #ID,Category,Sub Category,State Standard
      Charity.create!({
        :ein                              => row[0],
        :legal_name                       => row[1],
        :city                             => row[2],
        :state                            => row[3],
        :deductibility_status             => row[4],
        :country                          => row[5],
        :deductibility_status_description => row[6]
      })
    end
  end
end
```

finally you can run this import by typing following on command line from your rails app

```
 rake import:irs_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one idea, use a regex:

```
#!/opt/local/bin/ruby

fp = File.open("pipe_delim.txt")
r1 = /.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|.*?\|/m
results = fp.gets.scan(r1)
results.each do |result|
  puts result
end
```

This regex seems to trip up on newlines within a field, but I'm sure you could tweak it to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but the `cucumber` testing gem has a `Cucumber::Ast::Table` class you could use to process this file.

```
Cucumber::Ast::Table.new(File.read(file))
```

Then I think it's the `rows` method you can use to read it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String#split` and `Enumerable#each_slice`:

```
result = []
text.split('|').each_slice(7) { |record| result << record }
```